# How to get XslCompiledTransform to include xmlns in root element?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I'm trying to use XslCompiledTransform C# class to transform one xml file into another. However, the xmlns attribute is not being transferred.

My code:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("machine1.xml");
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("machine2.xml");

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load("transform.xsl");

transform.Transform(reader, writer);
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachines" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <!-- Copy everything not subject to the exceptions below -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Ignore the disabled element -->
  <xsl:template match="Disabled" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachines" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Machine>
      <Name>DellM7600</Name>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Type>Laptop</Type>
      <Disabled>false</Disabled>
      <SerialNum>47280420</SerialNum>
    </Machine>
    <Machine>
      <Name>DellD600</Name>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Type>Laptop</Type>
      <Disabled>false</Disabled>
      <SerialNum>53338123</SerialNum>
    </Machine>
    </ArrayOfMachine>
```

This is the actual Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachines" >
    <Machine>
      <Name>DellM7600</Name>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Type>Laptop</Type>
      <Disabled>false</Disabled>
      <SerialNum>47280420</SerialNum>
    </Machine>
    <Machine>
      <Name>DellD600</Name>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Type>Laptop</Type>
      <Disabled>false</Disabled>
      <SerialNum>53338123</SerialNum>
    </Machine>
    </ArrayOfMachine>
```

This is the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfMachine xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachines" >
    <Machine>
      <Name>DellM7600</Name>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Type>Laptop</Type>
      <SerialNum>47280420</SerialNum>
    </Machine>
    <Machine>
      <Name>DellD600</Name>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Type>Laptop</Type>
      <SerialNum>53338123</SerialNum>
    </Machine>
    </ArrayOfMachine>
```

Comment: your xml is not well formed.
<SerialNum>

Comment: Is that really the output you are getting? XsltCompiledTrasnform in C# is an XSLT 1.0 processor, so `xpath-default-namespace` is not be supported, and so the template matching `Disabled` should not be applied.

Comment: @AjeetSingh It was a copy/paste problem.

Comment: @TimC Yes, I got lost in a sea of frantic edits. What is now posted above is what I have but unfortunately it is just copying the source output to the destination output as you described. What am I doing wrong? I had this working before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were previously try to use `xpath-default-namespace` in your XSLT, which is not supported in XSLT 1.0.

Instead, you will need to use namespace prefix, bound to the namespace specified in your XML, to match the `Disabled` element which is in that namespace.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:cm="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CMachines" 
                              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <!-- Copy everything not subject to the exceptions below -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Ignore the disabled element -->
  <xsl:template match="cm:Disabled" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the namespace prefix used is arbitrary, as long as the namespace URI matches.